# Get coordinates from Folium's feature LocateControl() in Python

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, folium

I have this problem.

I have this to get the information from the mobile phone

```
from folium.plugins import LocateControl
m = folium.Map()
# With default settings
LocateControl().Add_to(m)
m
```

and I need to know the latitude

Does someone have the same requirement?